# I want query for show Table Result and Use MySQL query only

Tags: mysql

**TABLE  A**

```
ID   |   NAME
-----+-------
n1   |   BLACK
n2   |   WHITE
n3   |   RED
n4   |   GREEN
```

**TABLE  B**

```
ID |   A_ID  |   BLABLA      |    TIME
---+---------+---------------+--------
1  |   n1    |    X          | sometime
2  |   n1    |    X          | sometime
3  |   n1    |    X          | sometime
4  |   n1    |    Y          | sometime
5  |   n1    |    Z          | sometime
6  |   n2    |    Y          | sometime
7  |   n2    |    Y          | sometime
8  |   n2    |    Y          | sometime
9  |   n3    |    X          | sometime
10 |   n3    |    Z          | sometime
11 |   n3    |    Z          | sometime
12 |   n3    |    Z          | sometime
```

**My Question**

I want query for show Table Result and Use MySQL query only.

**TABLE RESULT**

```
NAME       |     X    |    Y    |    Z
-----------+----------+---------+-----
BLACK      |    3     |     1   |    0
WHITE      |    0     |     3   |    0
RED        |    1     |     0   |    3
GREEN      |    0     |     0   |    0
```

Comment: is it fixed that you would have only X, Y, Z as values (or columns in the result table)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  a.name
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.blabla LIKE 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS X
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.blabla LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.blabla LIKE 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Z
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON (a.id = b.a_id)
GROUP BY a.name
```

I use `like` instead of `=`, because `like` is always case-insensitive and `=` is not.
If `blabla` is an enum, then I recommend using `=`.